# Is there a nice way to get hash as a loop result in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

In coffeescript loops are expressions and returns an array. For example, we can do

```
func = (name) -> name.toUpperCase()
result = (func prop for prop in ['a', 'b'])
```

and get as a result:

```
['A','B']
```

But what if I want to get hash table (object) instead of array? 
How to modify the above example to get `{ a: 'A', b: 'B' }` ?

I know, that I can do id like this:

```
func = (name) -> name.toUpperCase()
result = {}
result[prop] = func prop for prop in ['a', 'b']
result
```

Too verbose! May be there is a nicer way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not as nice as a real object comprehension, you can use `Array::reduce` for this. For your example in particular, using a "transformer" function such as:

```
transform = (f) -> (prev, curr) ->
  prev[curr] = f curr
  prev
```

And your `func`:

```
func = (name) -> name.toUpperCase()
```

You can reduce your array with `transform` and `func` like so:

```
result = ['a', 'b'].reduce transform(func), {}
```

See [Approximating object comprehension one-liners in CoffeeScript using Array.reduce()](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/7329299) for a lengthier explanation and more examples.